# How to know the latest view controller in the view stack

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uiapplicationdelegate

Is there a way to know the current viewController in the memory. I am in a NSObject subclass which is being called from multiple view controllers. I do not want to add an extra parameter and pass it to my NSObject subclass. Is there any UIApplication method which I can call in my NSObject class to get the latest view controller in the memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because you're misunderstanding how view controllers work.  View controllers control a view.  That's it.  While a view may *usually* take up the entire screen, it doesn't have to.  For example, an iPad app with a split view controller and a visible UIPopoverController actually has (at least) 4 visible views all controlled by different view controllers.  There's the `UISplitViewController` and it's main content area, there's the `UIViewController` controlling the left ("master") area of the split view controller, another `UIViewController` controller the right ("detail") area of the split view controller, and a fourth view controller for controlling the contents of the popover.

Which one of those would you say is the "latest view controller"?

And the correct answer would be: none.

Comment: What about a iPhone application. At a given point in time there will be one view controller always top in the view hierarchy. By any chance does UIApplication know this view controller?

Comment: Well I think the same is true for IPhone. UIViewController has the view property to point at the view it manages. UIView class has the integer tag property to identify views.